# Curious as it may seem?

Tags: phrase-meaning

1. What does the phrase "curious as it may seem" mean?

Quoted from On 'The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences' by Sorin Bangu,

> Curious as it may seem, such explicit reconstructions of the problem are not
> common in the literature.

Does it mean "strange or unusual as it may seem"?

2. Taking into account the sentence as a whole, can the sentence be interpreted as:

> It is strange that such explicit reconstructions of the problem are not
> common in the literature.

3. Is this phrase equivalent to "curious though it may seem"?

Comment: Replacing “curious” with “strange” might be clearer usage.

Comment: Not _it is strange_, but _although it may seem strange_.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Curious as it may seem, such explicit reconstructions of the problem are not common in the literature.

> 2.It is strange that such explicit reconstructions of the problem are not common in the literature.

Yes, *curious* could take the meaning of *strange* or *unusual*.

The 2 examples above, however, have slightly different meanings.

Example 1 stresses the point, as stated in the main clause, *such explicit reconstructions of the problem are not common in the literature*.

Example 2 stresses the *strangeness* and suggests that such explicit reconstructions should be more common.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, “curious” here just means “odd,” unexpected,” “strange.” The most frequent meaning of “curious” is “inquisitive,” but it can also mean “generating inquiry because of strangeness.” This second, and far less common, meaning is embedded in the stock phrase “curious as it may seem.”